# Functor-Diagram in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I wonder how to draw the typical Functor-Diagram (picture below) in `tikz-cd`. I know how to draw commutative diagrams, however I don't know how to make the short `\mapsto` arrows as well as the mapsto arrow in between the vertical arrows. Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

**Edit** (code that produces errors, namely the `ngerman` package):

```
\documentclass{amsart}

%Standardpakete
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}


\begin{document}
$$
\begin{tikzcd}
\mathsf{C}^{\mathsf{op}} \arrow[rr, "F"] &  & \mathsf{D} \\
c \arrow[dd, "f"'] & \mapsto & Fc  \\
& \mapsto & \\
c' & \mapsto & Fc' \arrow[uu, "Ff"']
\end{tikzcd}
$$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
\mathsf{C}^{\mathsf{op}} \arrow[rr, "F"] &  & \mathsf{D} \\
c \arrow[dd, "f"'] & \mapsto & Fc  \\
& \mapsto & \\
c' & \mapsto & Fc' \arrow[uu, "Ff"']
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum on request of the user.** I think that the problem it is the `ngerman` babel. You can fix it putting,

```
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
```

---

```
\documentclass{amsart}

%Standardpakete
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\mathsf{C}^{\mathsf{op}} \arrow[rr, "F"] &  & \mathsf{D} \\
c \arrow[dd, "f"'] & \mapsto & Fc  \\
& \mapsto & \\
c' & \mapsto & Fc' \arrow[uu, "Ff"']
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: I am using the documentclass amsart and it appears that your code does not work in that class, do you know why or how to fix it?

Comment: @user243350 Here in this community it is necessary to add a minimal working example (a full code of your work). After I have tried with `amsart` class and the code work correctly.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry, I will try to extract the necessary piece of code of my document shortly. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: It appears there is nothing wrong with your code when I extract the necessary packages into a seperate argument, so there has to be some error on my side. I will try to fix it, thank you for your efforts!

Comment: I found the error but don't know how to fix it, perhaps you do. I edited the post and copied a sample code that produces the error I get and this is caused by the ngerman package I am using. If you know how to fix it I would be very greatful. I am selftaught in Latex so my knowledge is extremely limited.

Comment: @user243350 The problem it is the language. See my edit where I have added \usetikzlibrary{babel}. Keep in mind that I am not very good at LaTeX.  :-)..I remember to not use double $$ ...$$. It is depreciated.

Comment: Thank you so much once again, it has fixed the problem. Is there a reason for $$...$$ being depreciated? I think this would produce errors in this case and I use it all the time. Understanding why it is bad would probably help to know when to avoid using it.

Comment: @user243350 See, please, this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to [Sebastiano](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117876/sebastiano)'s great answer, it is possible to name the arrows `f` and `Ff` and add an arrow between them, then `shorten` the arrow:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=tiny]
\mathsf{C}^{\mathsf{op}} \arrow[r, "F"] &  \mathsf{D} \\
c \arrow[d, "f"'{name=f}]\arrow[r,mapsto] & Fc  \\[5ex]
c'\arrow[r,mapsto] & Fc' \arrow[u, "Ff"'{name=Ff}]
\arrow[mapsto,from=f, to=Ff,shorten=0.7em]
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

Another option could be add an empty arrow name in the inner part of the diagram and add the arrow as before

```
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=tiny]
\mathsf{C}^{\mathsf{op}} \arrow[r, "F"] &  \mathsf{D} \\
c \arrow[d, "f"', ""{name=f}]\arrow[r,mapsto] & Fc  \\[5ex]
c'\arrow[r,mapsto] & Fc' \arrow[u, "Ff"', ""{name=Ff}]
\arrow[mapsto,from=f, to=Ff]
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much to have cited me with....."to Sebastiano's great answer".

Comment: Well it does exactly what the OP asked, so it is great :)